# ERROR:can.socketcan.ctypes:Setting filters failed -1 Find out the can error frame

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, error-handling, embedded, can-bus

I am writing Python codes to `see the Error frames`. I want to set `Error Filters`. But this code never works when I set the `CAN_RAW_ERR_FILTER`. But the filter works when the filter set to `CAN_RAW_FILTER`.

`CanRecv.py` on `vcan0`

```
import can
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
def recv_one():
    bus = can.interface.Bus(bustype='socketcan', channel='vcan0', bitrate=250000, can_filters=[{"can_mask":0x1FFFFFFF, "can_id":0x20000000, "extended":True}])
    try:
        while 1: #print "bus: ", bus
            msg = bus.recv()
            print("Message recv : ", msg)
    except: # can.CanError:
        print("Eror")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    recv_one()
```

`CanSend.py`

```
import can
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
def send_one():
    bus = can.interface.Bus(bustype='socketcan', channel='vcan0', bitrate=250000, can_filters=[{"can_id": 0x11, "can_mask": 0x21, "extended": False}])
    msg = can.Message(arbitration_id=0xc0ffee,#0x20000088, #0xc0ffee,
                      data=[0, 25, 0, 1, 3, 1, 4, 1],
                      extended_id=True)
    try:
        print "bus: ", bus
        bus.send(msg)
        print("Message sent on {}".format(bus.channel_info))
    except can.CanError:
        print("Message NOT sent")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    send_one()
```

I tried to change the  library code like this,

```
def set_filters(self, can_filters=None):
    """Apply filtering to all messages received by this Bus.

    Calling without passing any filters will reset the applied filters.

    :param list can_filters:
        A list of dictionaries each containing a "can_id" and a "can_mask".

        >>> [{"can_id": 0x11, "can_mask": 0x21}]

        A filter matches, when ``<received_can_id> & can_mask == can_id & can_mask``

    """
    filter_struct = pack_filters(can_filters)
    print ("Filter Struct : ", filter_struct, type(filter_struct))
    res = libc.setsockopt(self.socket,
                          SOL_CAN_RAW,
                          CAN_RAW_ERR_FILTER, #CAN_RAW_FILTER,CAN_RAW_ERR_FILTER,
                          filter_struct, len(filter_struct)
                         )
    print("My Code")
    # TODO Is this serious enough to raise a CanError exception?
    if res != 0:
        log.error('Setting filters failed: ' + str(res))
```

The output comes as,

```
 DEBUG:can:can config: {'interface': 'socketcan_ctypes', 'channel': 'vcan0'}
INFO:can.socketcan.ctypes:Loading socketcan ctypes backend
INFO:can.socketcan.ctypes:Loading libc with ctypes
INFO:can.socketcan.native:Loading socketcan native backend
DEBUG:can.socketcan.native:CAN_* properties not found in socket module. These are required to use native socketcan
DEBUG:can.socketcan.ctypes:Result of createSocket was 3
DEBUG:can.socketcan.ctypes:Creating a filtered can bus
('Can_mask is : ', 536870911)
('The Pack_filer is :', [2684354560, 2684354559], {'can_id': 536870912, 'can_mask': 536870911, 'extended': True}, '=2I')
Filter Struct :  �����
My Code
ERROR:can.socketcan.ctypes:Setting filters failed: -1
DEBUG:can.socketcan.ctypes:Binding socket with id 3 to channel vcan0
DEBUG:can.socketcan.ctypes:calling ioctl SIOCGIFINDEX
INFO:can.socketcan.ctypes:ifr.ifr_ifindex: 22
DEBUG:can.socketcan.ctypes:bind returned: 0
DEBUG:can.socketcan.ctypes:Trying to read a msg
DEBUG:can.socketcan.ctypes:Receiving a message
```

Comment: "But this code never works, it works well when I set the CAN_RAW_ERR_FILTER. But the filter works when the filter set to CAN_RAW_FILTER." What do you mean here ?

Comment: Whenever I am setting the `CAN_RAW_ERR_FILTER` in library code `libc.setsockopt` I am always getting an error as `ERROR:can.socketcan.ctypes:Setting filters failed: -1`. But this works well with `CAN_RAW_FILTER`

Comment: I fixed the question

Answer (score 1):

From the library code you are showing :

`>>> [{"can_id": 0x11, "can_mask": 0x21}]
A filter matches, when <received_can_id> & can_mask == can_id & can_mask`

In your receiver, you set: `"can_mask":0x1FFFFFFF, "can_id":0x20000000` but `0x1FFF_FFFF & 0x2000_0000` is always 0. If you want to keep this mask, you should change the `can_id` field to the same value of the ID your are sending.

Also the can_id 0x2000_0000 is not possible on the bus as the maximum length of an ID is  29 bits and 0x2000_0000 is 30 bits.

Concerning your modifications of the library. It doesn't work because in socketCAN, the struct for the normal filters is:

```
struct can_filter {
    canid_t can_id;
    canid_t can_mask;
};
```

and for the errors:

```
typedef __u32 can_err_mask_t;
```

In your code you are changing the `CAN_RAW_FILTER` to `CAN_RAW_ERR_FILTER` but you are keeping the structure packing from the raw filters (`filter_struct = pack_filters(can_filters)`) which is not what is C function is expecting, hence the error.

To have your code working, you should write your own `pack_filters`. But I would rather recommend you not to modify the library and filter the errors with `if` statement for example.

Comment: So how can I fix it?

Comment: The value of can_id and can_mask in the doc string is an example I believe

Comment: I want to catch all the error frames the filters I am applying is not working. Is there anyway we can fix the set filter

Comment: Finally, I got it working with Python 3. Thanks all for your help.